# Batch file command line arguments parsing error if option starts with hypen

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the below command to invoke the executable:

```
start /wait %arg1%  -c %arg2%
```

I get an error window stating :

```
Windows cannot find '-c'. Make sure you typed the name correctly and try again
```

How can I fix the error - putting -c under single or double quotes does not helps either?

I tried from command prompt also:

```
.\run.bat "c:\Project Work\bin\test.exe"  c:\config.ini
ECHO is off. 
The system cannot find the file -c.
```

But both the exe and ini file exists.

Even running at prompt:

```
start /wait "c:\Project Work\bin\test.exe" -c c:\config.ini
```

gives the same issue - **Windows cannot find '-c'. Make sure you typed the name correctly and try again**

Comment: `"%arg1%"`  would be needed should that variable contain a path with spaces.

Comment: I have updated the question yes it has space

Comment: Oh how about `start "" /wait "c:\Project Work\bin\test.exe" -c c:\config.ini`

Comment: It works - I do not get the error - what is the issue and how it got fixed?

Comment: If you look at `start /?` the 1st quoted parameter is expected to be the title text for the window - not the path to the application to run. We just provided `""` to satisfy that requirement.